# How to mock UnitOfWork when using transactions (NUnit and NSubstitute)

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit, nsubstitute

I have created a Web API using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 5.0. Data is stored in a MSSQL database.
I have implemented UnitOfWork and repository pattern.

The UnitOfWork class has a method used to create transactions and it look like this:

```
//UnitOfWork
public async Task ExecuteTransaction(Func<Task> insideTransactionFunction)
{
  var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

  try
  {
    await insideTransactionFunction();
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    await transaction.RollbackAsync();
    throw;
  }
}
```

Im trying to write tests, for service classses that uses the UnitOfWork class to modify the data in the SQL database. Fx when adding a user using the UserService:

```
//UserService
public async Task<User> AddUserAsync(User user) 
{
   await _unitOfWork.ExecuteTransaction(async () =>
   {
      //Add user locally to generate the local id
      _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Add(user);
      await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

      //...Some logic that uses the generated user id...

      if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.User) == false)
      {
        //Inviting the user returns the generated Azure User id
        user.AzureUserId = _azureService.InviteUser(user.Email);
        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
      }
   }

   return user; 
}
```

A test for the above method could look like this:

```
//UserServiceTests
public async Task AddUserAsync_UserQualifiesForAzureInvite_AzureUserIdSetOnCreatedUser()
{
  //Arrange
  var unitOfWork = Substitute.For<IUnitOfWork>();
  var azureService = Substitute.For<IAzureService>();
  var uut = new UserService(unitOfWork, azureService);

  var newUser = new User { ... some setup ... };
  var azureUserId = Guid.NewGuid();
  azureService.InviteUser(null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(Task.FromResult(azureUserId));

  //Act
  var createdUser = await _uut.AddUserAsync(newUser); //Returns right away

  //Assert
  Assert.That(createdUser.AzureUserId, Is.EqualTo(azureUserId));
}
```

The problem is that the transaction created with UnitOfWork is ignored and the user is returned straight away.

```
public async Task<User> AddUserAsync(User user) 
{
   //Skipped from here...
   await _unitOfWork.ExecuteTransaction(async () =>
   {
      //
   }
   //...To here

   return user; 
}
```

So my question is: How can i mock the UnitOfWork class and still be able to test code wrapped in the the transaction?

Comment: You don't need an additional Unit-of-Work to begin with. DbContext *is* a Unit-of-Work. So your real question becomes how to mock a DbContext - use the in-memory provider

Comment: BTW if you used EF Core properly you wouldn't need an explicit transaction. That explicit transaction just broke both UoW and EF Core. EF Core, just like any data access method since the late 1990s works *disconnected*. Nothing at all is saved to the server until a call to `SaveChanges` is made. You get UoW for free this way. By imposing a Data-Access-Object (that's not a repository) API on top of the ORM though, you now need an explicit database transaction. This lost every data access benefit discovered in the last 25 years

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for Repository or Unit of Work with EF Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for a detailed explanation of what's wrong with the current code. Also read Oren Eini's [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton) from 2009. That's how long people knew about the problems with "repositories". Oren Eini, aka Ayende, is a .NET legend, at the time the maintainer of NHibernate and the creator of RavendB

Comment: Alright, seems i have over complicated things here. I need the call to ```SaveChanges``` to get the id of the user though (because i need this id for other operations). Or am i missing something there also?

Comment: You can use a DbContext with the in-memory provider instead of a real database. Check [the EF Core testing article in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/testing-sample). Despite the name it's essentially a wrapper over a dictionary. You can specify different providers by passing a different `DbContextOptions` parameter to your DbContext constructor

Comment: DB-generated IDs are supported by the in-memory provider already. That's not a database though, even though it's better than a simple mock. You can use other providers, like SQLite in in-memory mode to get something closer to a real database's behavior. The problems with mocking EF Core [are known and the various techniques are described in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/)

Comment: One thing that I haven't noticed before though is : `We use test doubles for internal testing of EF Core. However, we never try to mock DbContext or IQueryable. Doing so is difficult, cumbersome, and fragile. **Don't do it**.` Emphasis by the EF Core team itself.

Comment: BTW in `AddUserAsync` you won't need an explicit transaction if you only call `SaveChangesAsync` only once, just before disposing the DbContext/Unit-of-Work. `SaveChangesAsync` persists *all* changes to the database in an internal transaction. If you need a generated ID inside the UoW's scope, using an explicit transaction won't work quite the way you expect it to - that ID value won't be regenerated even after a rollback. You could generate that ID on the client, eg using a sequential GUID generator. Or you could use eg a `SEQUENCE` in the database and asks for a new value at the start

Comment: You can borrow the code from EF Core's [SequentialGuidValueGenerator](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ValueGeneration/SequentialGuidValueGenerator.cs) which uses the same algorithm as SQL Server's `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. The algorithm is ... annoyingly simple

Comment: Thank you for all the helpfull links and explanations! I think im on the right track now, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

My architecture was fundamentally flawed. Check out the comments and links made by Panagiotis Kanavos.

The solution was to get rid of UnitOfWork and the repositories and it seems testable now.